# insert text between the top and bottom of the hamburger mobile menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

I have a mobile menu "Hamburger", consisting of three stripes. Trying to embed text between the top and bottom. It should turn out, as in the picture (in the question). It doesn’t work, in any way. How to do this, tell me, please. Thank.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaSG2.png

```css
#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    #header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before {
        top: 0;
        transform: rotate(0);
    }

    #header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
        top: 0;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    #header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_content_one_menu {
        visibility: visible;
        left: 0;
    }

 
      .header_menu_adaptive_button {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;   
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;  
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 3;
        padding: 0 20px 0 0;
      }
      
      .header_menu_adaptive_button > span,
      .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before,
      .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 3px;  
        background-color: red;    
        transition-duration: .25s;
        z-index: 11112;
      }
      .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::before {
        content: '';
        top: -8px;
      }
      .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
        content: '';
        top: 8px;
      }
      
      .header_content_one_menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-row-gap: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        top: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
        left: -100%;     
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 30px 0 30px 0;    
        background-color: green;
        transition-duration: .25s;
      }
```

```html
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">
         <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
         <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
         <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the code comments in the code snippets for the change details. I hope this satisfies your requirement.

```css
#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  visibility: hidden;  /* Add visibility */
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
  visibility: visible;  /* Add visibility */
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  visibility: visible;  /* Add visibility */
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_content_one_menu {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-duration: .25s; */
  color: red; /* Added */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* Added */
  font-size: 14px; /* Added */
  z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
  width: 50px; /* Added */
  height: 3px; /* Added */
  background-color: red; /* Added */
  transition-duration: .25s; /* Added */
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 20px; /* Change 8px to 20px */
  width: 50px; /* Added */
  height: 3px; /* Added */
  background-color: red; /* Added */
  transition-duration: .25s; /* Added */
}

.header_content_one_menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  background-color: green;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

```html
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox" />
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>MEH &#1070</span> <!-- Added the MEH word -->
                    </label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```